# How do short-term commodity price fluctuations work?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Recently I did a mining run in a refinery/extraction system and, since I'm lazy, I was selling everything I mined to a station in that system. After several mining runs (3 runs, approx 2 hrs of game time), I had sold about 50 units of Painite for just above galactic average. On the fourth run, the price suddenly dropped to 3/4 galactic average.

So, I looked at trade routes and found a high tech / industrial system about 40ly away, and BAM they were buying Painite for 75,000 creds a pop. I made quite a little bundle by selling 25 units of Painite.

**So**, I did that run again immediately: back to extraction system A for Painite and whatever else I could find, then back to industrial system B for the market. Upon my return, the market price for Painite had *dropped in the span of an hour* to just under galactic average, about half the price of my previous visit.

The [wiki entry for commodities](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Commodities) does say that prices can change daily, specifically due to player interaction, but I can vouch that I am not in a highly trafficked system, and I haven't spent time here before...

> The availability of certain commodities can vary greatly from station to station. Generally stations will produce and consume certain commodities based upon their economy type. Prices of commodities are dynamic and will fluctuate based on a variety of factors, including as a direct result of player interaction. Trade routes and strategies can change on a day to day basis - especially in areas with a high amount of player activity.

My question is, how do these short- term (e.g. in one game session) price changes work? Did I just catch an unlucky server-side update that rolled a bad Painite price at both stations? Or can a couple units (25-50?) of an item change a station's supply/demand that drastically, in that short of a time span?

Comment: IIRC a lot of it is based on Supply / Demand, including what happens in Open / Private / Solo.  So any you supply will reduce the demand, and so kill your price.